# Entity Framework Code First Self-Referencing Many-to-Many with additional properties using wrong Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

I'm trying to model a self-referencing Many-to-Many relationship between Employees and Managers using EF code first (where managers are employees). On top of keeping track of which managers an Employee has I need to store a managers rank. I'm assuming I'll need to create a linking class so that I can store the rank.

My POCO classes look something like this:

```
public class Employee
{
public Guid EmployeeId {get; set;}
public String Name {get; set;}
public virtual ICollection<EmployeeManagers> EmployeeManagers { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeManager
{
public int EmployeeManagerId {get; set;}
public int Rank {get; set;}
public Guid EmployeeId {get; set;}
public Guid ManagerId {get; set;}
public virtual Employee Manager {get; set;}
}
```

It seems to work fine except when I use the Manager object in the EmployeeManager class. It is using the EmployeeId to load the Manager object instead of the ManagerId. So if an employee has 4 managers, it loads the Employee into the Manager object instead of the 4 managers.

Have I modelled this correctly and is there a way to force EF to use the ManagerId to load the Manager?

**EDIT:**

Anyone have any idea why the entity framework would use the **EmployeeId** to try load the Manager? The order that the properties appear in doesn't make any difference and surely **ManagerId** is a more likely foreign key for loading a Manager than **EmployeeId**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by adding the ForeignKey attribute:

```
    [ForeignKey("ManagerId")]
    public virtual Employee Manager { get; set; }
```